# Mark rectangle on an image inside a web page for region of interest selection

Tags: javascript

I'd like to mark a rectangle on an image in a web page for region of interest selection. Meaning, given an image on a web page I'd like to be able to click-drag with a mouse that will draw a rectangle and return a set of x,y,w,h upon mouse release.

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you have an image, and you want to be able to draw a rectangle inside of the image?

Just create an absolutely positioned div inside of the image with a border.

Add a mousedown handler to the image that gets the location of the click, then a handler for the current position of the cursor location until mouseup.

In the handler for current position of the cursor - set the dimensions of your div. On mouseup, stop resizing the div.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with a little positioning trick. Set the image in a div positioned relatively. Then you can create an absolute positioned div inside of the div that contains the image as well. This allows you to move the nested div around the front of the image.

As per your update, I have added some javascript that controls the inner div's x,y,w,h on `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup`

**NOTE:** since this js snippet uses clientX/Y and offsetLeft/Top, the preview below may run a bit off because of its overflow container inside of the post page. I recommend viewing the "Run code snippet" in full screen mode.

```js
var x,y,oldx,oldy;
var showDrag = false;
document.getElementById("cont").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  oldx = e.clientX; //mousedown x coord
  oldy = e.clientY; //mouedown y coord
  showDrag = true;
  e.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("cont").addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (showDrag == true) {
    x = e.clientX; //mouseup x coord
    y = e.clientY; //mouseup y coord
    var bbox = document.getElementById("bbox");
    var contbox = document.getElementById("cont");
    //get the width and height of the dragged area
    var w = (x > oldx ? x-oldx : oldx-x);
    var h = (y > oldy ? y-oldy : oldy-y);
    var addx = 0, addy = 0;
    //these next two lines judge if the box was dragged backward
    //and adds the box's width to the bbox positioning offset
    if (x < oldx) { addx = w; }
    if (y < oldy) { addy = h; }
    bbox.style.left = (oldx-parseInt((contbox.offsetLeft+addx)))+"px";
    bbox.style.top = (oldy-parseInt((contbox.offsetTop+addy)))+"px";
    bbox.style.width = w+"px";
    bbox.style.height = h+"px";
    bbox.style.display = "block";
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("cont").addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  showDrag = false;
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
div.focus-image {
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}
div.focus-image div {
  display:none;
  border:2px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  left:90px; /*x*/
  top:60px; /*y*/
}
```

```html
<div id="cont" class="focus-image">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" />
  <div id="bbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my question to clarify what I meant.

Comment: @miluz sorry for the late reply. I have updated my answer to include a javascript snippet that controls the inner bordered div. Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Thank you. Real problem solver.